# --resource-rules has been deprecated in mac os x >= 10.10

Tags: ios, iphone, code-signing, ipa, osx-yosemite

I tried to resign my ipa file with new provisioning profile on Mac Os 10.10 with iResign app but I got this warning: "Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10".

What should I do now?

Comment: What files are you excluding from signing?

Comment: I have an ipa file with development cerfiticate, now I want to change it to an enterprise distribution cerfiticate. I used iResign app to resign on Mac OS X 10.10 but it shows that warning.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `iResign` (whatever that is) and you should probably be rebuilding the app using Xcode instead?

Comment: Thanks for your support. But some of my friends don't know how to build with Xcode. It's better if they can resign ipa file with their distribution cerfiticate. I will suggest they use Mac OS 10.9.5 or below. Anyway, thankyou very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found **workaround**: if you run the iResign app from XCode — then you will resign app without problem (warning will appears in console instead of popup).
But if you close XCode and run app alone — then popup will back to you!

BTW: bug found :)
The condition

```
if (systemVersionFloat < 10.9f)
```

Is broken for Yosemite 10.10. Funny.

Thanks,

Comment: Thankyou very much! This is really a funny bug. I've found this bug recently. There is also new update here: https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign

Comment: Where is the condition coming from? And how should I fix this condition?

Comment: This doesn't look like a bug as much as a hardcoded force-deprecation.

Answer (score 154):

Click on your project > Targets > Select your target > Build Settings >

`Code Signing Resource Rules Path`

and add :

`$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist`

[image]

Comment: Any explanation behind what exactly changed to cause this error?

Comment: Not sure. I think it's Apple's engineers you should ask hehe :) @Johannes: Are you sure you did the exact steps ? Not sure how I can actually help you, though I want that ... :(

Comment: This helped me solve an issue that I was having with TestFlight.

Comment: I don't see `Code Signing Resource Rules Path` there... Any ideas?

Comment: This seemed to have solved issues i was having with TestFlight

Comment: go to `Build Settings` Georg and make sure you have all levels selected

Comment: This solved my problem using TestFlight for Mac when creating the IPA failed.

It honestly feels like apple is slowly killing everything good about TestFlight. I thought it was gonna be a good thing when they acquired...

Comment: To save someone else some time 'Code Signing Resource Rules Path' is under the fourth section 'Code Signing'.

Comment: This did NOT work for me however I found my resolution.  In my case I am building a Mac app.  I recently migrated to a new iMac using a restore from Time Machine backup (not sure if that is relevant).  I also am newly using XCode 6.1.  In my case I went to the developer portal and registered my new Mac's UUID as a device and added that to my provisioning profile.  Then I manually downloaded/installed that profile but it still did not work. THEN I went into XCode Preferences... Accounts, double-clicked my account and clicked the Refresh button. FINALLY I got the build to work.

Comment: This answer does not apply to OS X targets, since the `ResourceRules.plist` file on Mac OS can be found few levels up in the `$(SDKROOT)` path.

Comment: @danipralea: Though the solution provided by you works just perfectly, I have one concern. I just came across the Apple's technical note from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG401. It says that "Code Signing Resource Rules Path build setting in Xcode should no longer be used and should be left blank.". Please advice on this. Will the app be rejected by Apple if I use that flag. Is there anyway to remove that flag from codesign parameters?

Comment: My app was actually just approved with that setting. And it's not the only one

Comment: Added a screenshot because the Code Signing section can be tricky to find for the uninitiated (ie. me)

Comment: apple is now rejecting binaries that have this set.

Answer (score 24):

Since *Xcode 7*, the `Code Signing Resource Rules Path` *build setting* must be left empty or else this warning is produced.

[*Technical Note TN2206*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG206) provides the details:

> **Resource Rules**
>
> Systems before OS X Mavericks v10.9 documented a
>   signing feature (--resource-rules) to control which files in a bundle
>   should be sealed by a code signature. This feature has been obsoleted
>   for Mavericks. Code signatures made in Mavericks and later always seal
>   all files in a bundle; there is no need to specify this explicitly any
>   more. This also means that the Code Signing Resource Rules Path build
>   setting in Xcode should no longer be used and should be left blank.
>
> It is thus no longer possible to exclude parts of a bundle from the
>   signature. Bundles should be treated as read-only once they have been
>   signed.

Comment: Good info, though this seems to imply the *opposite* of the solutionfrom  the highest voted answer above... :S

Comment: I guess the highest voted answer was correct as of *Xcode 6.x*. It did not work on my case.

Comment: Correct answer needs to be updated to this as of XCode 7

Answer (score 10):

After Xcode 7 previous solutions stopped working. A new one was pointed by Rishi Goel (in https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762413/2252465)

1. Remove `CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH=$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist`
2. Find the `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication` script and update it.
   Find the lines including the following code in the script

   ```
   my @codesign_args = ("/usr/bin/codesign", "--force", "--preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules",
                     "--sign", $opt{sign},
                     "--resource-rules=$destApp/ResourceRules.plist");
   ```

   change it to:

   ```
   my @codesign_args = ("/usr/bin/codesign", "--force", "--preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements",
                     "--sign", $opt{sign});
   ```

Comment: That's actually the only solution that works. Thanks.

Comment: This is the solution in my opinion

Comment: cant unlock this file

Answer (score 4):

Try adding below arguments in xcodebuild command.

```
-sdk iphoneos CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH='$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are resigning app using terminal then you can even omit `resource-rules` while performing code sign, as there is no need to externally specify which resource to sign and which to not. Now it is mandatory to sign all the resources inside package.

To resign app using terminal you can follow below steps:

```
unzip MyApp.ipa

rm -rf Payload/MyApp.app/_CodeSignature/

cp ~/Desktop/MyAdHoc.mobileprovision Payload/MyApp.app/embedded.mobileprovision 

codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Code signing Certificate for Enterprise or Ad-hoc app" Payload/MyApp.app

zip -qr MyApp_Resigned.ipa Payload/
```

Answer (score 1):

I just opened my existing iOS app in Xcode 7 GM (from Xcode 6.4) and saw this deprecation warning.

It's interesting that answers and comments are saying to update the 'Code Signing Resource Rules Path' and they also reference Mac apps.

In my case, the project had this key and value already set by default (I never set it).  The warning is about resource rules being deprecated too.

For me, deleting the value of the 'Code Signing Resource Rules Path' removed the warning.  I have not submitted a new build this way so I may have to come back and update this answer.

Just thought it was interesting that my answer is opposite what everyone else was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out the two --resource-rules parameters from the arguments list, where the iResign app calls the codesign task, then you don't have to change the project build settings for the app's project.

I don't like the idea of having to modify the build settings for every project I want to work with, just so that I can resign it.

I rebuilt the resign tool, and copied it to my Applications directory, so that I don't have to open it in Xcode.